# ng-repeat filter to reset after I hide the search textfield

Tags: angularjs

I've a search type textfield serving as a filter for the ng-repeat list.

```
<div class="search pull-right">
    <div class="magnify"><img src="img/magnify.png" ng-click="magnify()"></div>
</div>
<div class="search-box" ng-show="showSearch">
    <input type="search" id="searchField" name="" value="" placeholder="Search" class="textfield" ng-model="search.firstName" /> 
</div>
```

once I hide the search field, the results are stucked and not getting reset,

in the magnify function defined on scope I'm setting showSearch to true/false

Things I've tried without success.

```
document.getElementById("searchField").value = "";
$scope.search.firstName='';
```

and my template

```
<li class="table-view-cell attendee" ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:search">
    <h2 class="name">{{attendee.firstName}} {{attendee.lastName}}</h2>
    <span class="job">{{attendee.title}}</span>
    <span class="company">{{attendee.company}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the filter "object" as the criteria (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), Angular will try to match `attendee`'s properties against properties of `search`. In order to reset the filter, you need to do

```
$scope.search = {};
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined on $scope.search, also I'm bootstrapping angular

Comment: however, the another property on the same scope is accessible and works, `showSearch`, I was able to show and hide textField, maybe something with this dot (search.firstName)

Comment: try the latest version of the answer. Just tested it with Google's "phone catalog" angular example app, seems to work.

Comment: Glad I could help. Learned something new about Angular along the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your data type is an object do

```
$scope.search = {};
```

If your data type is a string do

```
$scope.search = '';
```

Do Not make the mistake of trying to set it to null because that will not work